# ASP.NET core 2.0 web application deployment on iisexpress using VS2017 results in HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Deploying an ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC web application using Visual Studio 2017 (Preview) displays the error page in the browser saying:

> HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway
>   The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process.

**Works well when switched to `.NET Core 1.1` or `.NET Core 1.0`.** But when I build and deploy with `.NET Core 2.0` it displays the above error page in the browser.

Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed the issue with re-creating the application project with `.netcore 2.0` in a project creating a wizard in VS2017.

[image: New Application creation wizard - VS2017]
The issue might be with switching to `.netcore 2.0` after creating the project.